# MultiReason Exception in amphp/paralell

Tags: php, amphp

I'm trying to call multiples request to some webservices.
And I can't figure out how to do this.

I'm getting this error:

> Amp\MultiReasonException
>   Multiple errors encountered

I'm trying with this structure:

```
        $arr =["ACT","BKH"];

        $values = Promise\wait(parallelMap($arr, function ($time) {
            $start = \microtime(true);            
            //\sleep($time); // a blocking function call, might also do blocking I/O here

            //print_r($time); echo "</br>";
            $str ="Sin procesar";
            if ($time == "BKH"){
                $start = \microtime(true);            
                //Yii::info('Procesando ...'.var_dump($time));
                //---- desde aca ----

                //---- hasta aca ----
                $str = '('.$time .') Took ' . (\microtime(true) - $start) . ' seconds.';
    //                Yii::info('fin proceso ...  demora: '.$str);

            }
    return  $str;
        }));
```

I'm running this with Yii framework.

If I uncomment `Yii::info(...)` I get the error.

Because I need to consume web service, y added this between "//---- desde aca ----" and "//---- hasta aca ----"...

```
         $client= new SoapClient($url_wsdl, array('trace' => 1,
                                         'exceptions' => 1,
                                         "connection_timeout" => 5000/1000,
                                         'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP, 
                                         'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                                         'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1'));
```

and it works, `$url_wsdl` is validated, but when I try to use another function, I get the error again..

The function is:

```
$obj = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);
```

I don't know where to look for examples (I already looked in examples folder)
I can call native functions of php ??

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

okey !!
What happens is that if there is an error in the function, the error is Excepted...

in my case, I have some variables not defined, and I should use new \SoapVar